# C++ Return Performance

Tags: c++

I have a question about performance. I think this can also applies to other languages (not only C++).

Imagine that I have this function:

```
int addNumber(int a, int b){
    int result = a + b;
    return result;
}
```

Is there any performance improvement if I write the code above like this?

```
int addNumber(int a, int b){
     return a + b;
}
```

I have this question because the second function doesn´t declare a 3rd variable. But would the compiler detect this in the first code?

Comment: It depends on your compiler, and, within the compiler, its optimization settings. It's nevertheless a pretty good fit for optimization – probably even gets silently replaced by an inline calculation.

Comment: Most compilers will generate exactly the same assembly for both functions when optimizations are turned on.

Comment: You can compile it, look at the resulting assembly, and see for yourself.

Comment: Compilers haven't had a problem with this in half a century or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer this question you can [look at the generated assembler code](http://gcc.godbolt.org/). With -O2, x86-64 gcc 6.2 generates exactly the same code for both methods:

```
addNumber(int, int):
    lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
    ret
addNumber2(int, int):
    lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
    ret
```

Only without optimization turned on, [there is a difference](https://godbolt.org/g/Qfs4rO):

```
addNumber(int, int):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     eax, edx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    pop     rbp
    ret
addNumber2(int, int):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    add     eax, edx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

However, performance comparison without optimization is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

In principle there is no difference between the two approaches.   The majority of compilers have handled this type of optimisation for some decades.

Additionally, if the function can be inlined (e.g. its definition is visible to the compiler when compiling code that uses such a function) the majority of compilers will eliminate the function altogether, and simply emit code to add the two variables passed and store the result as required by the caller.

Obviously, the comments above assume compiling with a relevant optimisation setting (e.g. not doing a debug build without optimisation).

Personally, I would not write such a function anyway.   It is easier, in the caller, to write `c = a + b` instead of `c = addNumber(a, b)`, so having a function like that offers no benefit to either programmer (effort to understand) or program (performance, etc).   You might as well write comments that give no useful information.

```
 c = a + b;    //   add a and b and store into c
```

Any self-respecting code reviewer would complain bitterly about uninformative functions or uninformative comments.

I'd only use such a function if its name conveyed some special meaning (i.e. more than just adding two values) for the application

```
 c = FunkyOperation(a,b);

 int FunkyOperation(int a, int b)
 {
    /*  Many useful ways of implementing this operation.
           One of those ways happens to be addition, but we need to
           go through 25 pages of obscure mathematical proof to
           realise that
    */

    return a + b;
 }
```